# AngularJS : how to search text on table in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to search text on table using angular ..I am able to search text in table .But my search works when I press enter or “search button” .Example when I write “Active” it not show the result but when I press enter or press search button it show the output .can we do the like search like autocomplete .Example when I press “a’ it show all item which start from “a” .Then if user write “ac” then show “ac” value ..same like that .when user write “active “ it show rows which have “active” without using search button or enter

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/AmGcg) should be helpful. You can do this, if you look, using **ng-repeat**. Doing so, you essentially "repeatedly press enter" as text is put in.

For their example `ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:search | orderBy:'title':reverse">`

Hope this helps!

Comment: please remove your anser so that other will answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this. I can post a reply with your code later this weekend. As long as you don't select my answer, your question will still have exposure!